# PHP 7 - Warning: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Tags: php, symfony, command, php-7

I just found something weird in my project. I am using PHP7.3 and I am trying to make use of the `array_column()` function with objects.

I am using a command to call a service in  a symfony project - if that matters, however I have simplified my code to the minimum important.

**Article.php**:

```
class Article {
    private $id;
    private $category;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->category = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getCategory(): Collection
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function addCategory(ArticleCategory $category): self
    {
        if (!$this->category->contains($category)) {
            $this->category[] = $category;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCategory(ArticleCategory $category): self
    {
        if ($this->category->contains($category)) {
            $this->category->removeElement($category);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**ArticleCategory.php**

```
class ArticleCategory
{
    private $id;
    private $name;

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
```

I am trying to get the categories of an article as an array - for this case I use following:

`$categories = array_column($a->getCategory(), 'name'); //$a is the article object`

However this throws following warning:
`Warning: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given`

---

**What I already tried**

- make the `private $name` public
- add the functions `__get()` and `__isset()` with `private $name`

However none of this works for me. Even though array_column should work with objects in PHP >7 ?
I appreciate any help

Comment: Can you share the reference link why do believe the object is supported? as per the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):
A multi-dimensional **array** or an **array** of objects is allowed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need array use this `$categories = $a->getCategory()->toArray();`

If you you need array of category names - use array map

```
$categoriesName = $a->getCategory()->map(function(ArticleCategory $category) { 
    return $category->getName(); 
});
```

Comment: Yeah, but if you need array of names of your categories, use array map

Comment: the `map` function seems to return an `ArrayCollection` instead of an `array`

Comment: Yes, it be new ArrayCollection of category names, but you can call ->toArray()